# Create a shared object from linked binary

Tags: shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Assume a ready-to-run linked (C++) program `a.out` created with `g++` and `ld`. Is there a way to create a shared object library `liba.so` that contains all functions or at least `main` of the original program.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a miniature wrapper library with a single function `main` that executes your `a.out`... That way you need not try to do any decompilation magic at all.